# Breath of the Wild - Divine Beast Vah Medoh Glitch

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've finished all four of the individual Divine Beast Quests, but the main "Free the Divine Beasts" quest still says "there is one left". When I beat Vah Medoh I saw no cutscene, like the other beasts, where it was shooting the laser thing towards the Castle, I was never given Revali's Gale, and when I fast-travel to Vah Medoh I end up on that really tall rock near Rito Village but Medoh is nowhere to be found... Anyone experience this glitch and/or know any way to fix it?

**Update:** Just beat the game and the cutscene w/ Medoh firing the laser occurred, but I still never received Revali's Gale.

**Second Update:** Played through the game fresh from the start and did not encounter this issue the second time around.

Comment: Is the beast still accessible? May be you beat the boss but forgot to activate the beast control center?

Comment: No it's not. The control center is how I got off the beast.

Comment: Be sure to check the orni training area where there is the guy who takes you to the beast the first time, may be he can provide some help (access again the beast)... ?

Comment: Tried talking to everyone in town, nobody was able to help. I genuinely think this may just be a bug.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to fix it would be to load a previous save and fight the boss once again. I know it's a struggle, but right now its the only way.

Comment: That was literally like 4 hours of gameplay ago

Comment: well if there is no save for it anymore, than there is no known way right now. I will see if I can figure it out. :P